# How to override ActiveRecord CRUD operations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, activemodel

Is it possible that I create my model using "rails generate model..." which creates all them CRUD stuff including views for create, update and delete, AND then I override rails CRUD methods to do something else instead for example printing them all out or whatever?

I need to instead encode my model into JSON and send that to a middleware that will save it into a database.

A small example will really help... thanks a lot...

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer to my question that I have eventually found is to use ActiveModel instead.

Thanks for you input lads!

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that really connects scaffold to ActiveRecord is `class Model << ActiveRecord::Base`. So just take that away.

Then run the scaffold and take away the line at the top of the class that inherits from ActiverRecord. After that you need to connect to your db with whatever you want.

Comment: but taking off the ActiveRecord::Base wouldn't allow all the validation features that come with it, would it? And will my model still stay connected to them views?
I'm new to rails. I'll give it a go and see what happens.

Comment: It's not hard to write custom validations.

Comment: I agree, I just thought overriding a few methods would be as simple as they are in Java and C++ and I could really use some nice features that come with ActiveRecord...